# Resize background image like a ordinary img tag

Tags: css

Yesterday I visited Artstation and I noticed a cool effect on the main background image at the top for each profile on Artstation. If you resize the window from desktop size to the left and make the window smaller, the image starts to resize and at approximately 1430 px inner size and end at approximately 1010 px inner size and after that it stops resize. The resizing is just like when you resize a common image, but this is a background image. This effect is nice for a responsive design.

I have tried to inspect the CSS, but I can't find the answer. Someone who can tell me how this is done?

This is a randomly selectedthe profile that I was looking at to show what I mean:

https://www.artstation.com/gaelleseguillon

When I try to use a background image I use this code:

```
.topContainerBackground
{
background-image: url(../imagesLayout/background.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #000;
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

But as I wrote, I don't get the resize thing at approximately 1430 px inner size.

Comment: did you go through the mediaqueries too ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I tried to lacate the media queries and download the CSS file, but the code was minified and hard to read. Do you think it's a media query thing that do the resize of the background image lower the 1430 px?

Comment: looks like mediaquerie is involved. You can eventually load the css file into your css editor (or an online tool) and use the 'tidy' option to indent and make code readable ;) (give a try with https://codepen.io/pen or http://jsfiddle.net )

Comment: a min-height could do too https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxvvLM

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` is the key here. `1430px` has no real significance, it's a function of the proportions of the background image.

When a window is really wide, `cover` background sizing is mostly responding to the vertical height of the container, stretching the image to match vertically.

Once you start shrinking the window, there comes a point where height is no longer the primary concern, width is. That is where the image seems to begin scaling horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I use a copy of the same image, and I use background-size: cover, but there is no resizing!? Below 1430 px, the background image starts to get smaller in height, that is impossible with "cover". When I resize my window, it's the same height all the time and in the end, in mobile view, I see the center of the image. Could it be some kind of media queries that resize the image?

Comment: I don't think so. I did not see any media queries. This effect is a very elegant, simple illusion.